# Insecure PHP Login Form Exercise (Returns no errors, can't figure it out.)

Tags: php, forms

I have a Login script (it's a basic demonstration exercise of PHP for the web class i'm in) that is insecure, but intentionally so. Advice regarding exploits will go unnoticed, as this is for testing purposes only.

I have stumped the teacher. The code I have written has been bugfixed a number of times, yet my code still does not run correctly. I double-checked the functions I was using with the version of PHP on my webhost (I'm running 5.4) to make sure things were correctly written.

We can't figure out what's wrong. Maybe someone else can?

Here's the three files:

**login.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="process.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="pass"><br>
<input type="submit">   
<?php
        if (isset($_SESSION ["errorwelcome"])){
          echo ($_SESSION ["errorwelcome"]);
          unset($_SESSION ["errorwelcome"]);
      }
      if (isset($_SESSION ["errorunpass"])){
          echo ($_SESSION ["errorunpass"]);
          unset($_SESSION ["errorunpass"]);
      }
    ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**process.php**

```
    <?php
if ($_POST ["name"] == "shmailey"){
        if ($_POST ["pass"] == "password"){
            $_SESSION["login"] = 1; 
            header('Location: welcome.php');
            exit;
        }
}

    if ($_POST ["name"] != "shmailey"){
            $_SESSION ["errorunpass"] = "Uh oh, we didn't recognize those credentials. Incorrect Username and/or Password.";
            header('Location: login.php');
            exit;
    }
    ?>
```

**welcome.php**

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION ["login"])){
        unset ($_SESSION["login"]);
        }
    else{
            $_SESSION["errorwelcome"] = "You need to login first.";
            unset ($_SESSION["login"]);
            header('Location: login.php');
            exit;
        }
    ?>
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        echo "Login Success";
        echo "Username: shmailey";
        echo "Password: password";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you calling session_start() somewhere? Also, you need to say what the observed behavior is, not just "it doesn't do what I expect" - what does it do that you don't want? What doesn't it do that you do want?

Comment: "still does not run correctly" is pretty broad - how did you detect that? What **exactly** does not work, and what have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't start your sessions. You must start sessions using `session_start();` before using any session variables. Try the following code:

Login.php:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="process.php" method="post">
            Username: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            Password: <input type="text" name="pass"><br>
            <input type="submit">   
            <?php
                if (isset($_SESSION ["errorwelcome"])) {
                    echo $_SESSION ["errorwelcome"];
                    unset($_SESSION ["errorwelcome"]);
                }
                if (isset($_SESSION ["errorunpass"])) {
                    echo $_SESSION ["errorunpass"];
                    unset($_SESSION ["errorunpass"]);
                }
            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

process.php:

```
session_start();
if ($_POST["name"] == "shmailey" && $_POST["pass"] == "password"){
    $_SESSION["login"] = 1; 
    header('Location: welcome.php');
    die();
} else {
    $_SESSION["errorunpass"] = "Uh oh, we didn't recognize those credentials. Incorrect Username and/or Password.";
    header('Location: login.php');
    die();
}
```

welcome.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION ["login"])){
        unset ($_SESSION["login"]);
    } else {
        $_SESSION["errorwelcome"] = "You need to login first.";
        unset ($_SESSION["login"]);
        header('Location: login.php');
        die();
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo "Login Success";
            echo "Username: shmailey";
            echo "Password: password";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

From the little testing I did, it seems to work when including the session starts.

EDIT--
Patrick M noticed this in the comments of the question, I did not see that until after I posted the answer.